# liferay running slow

Tags: tomcat6, ehcache, c3p0, liferay-6

I have installed Liferay-Tomcat 6.0.6 on one of my Linux machine having 4GB of RAM and it uses MySQL installed on a different machine.

The liferay runs really slow even for 10 concurrent users.

I have attached the screen shot taken from the AppDynamics which shows EhCache and C3PO both are responding slow at times.

[image]

Are there any special config required for EhCache or C3PO??

I am currently running with default configurations.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me the methodology for deriving those stats?  In most cases, this behavior comes down to poor code implementation in a custom portlet or a JVM configuration issue and more likely the latter.  Take a look at the [Ehcache Garbage Collection Tuning Documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/garbage-collection).  When you run `jstat`, how do the garbage collection times look?